# Displaying Twitter Handle Using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This might be really simple question and I though the `<text>` tags were the answer but they do not seem to be working on my part.

I simply want to display @azamsharp in my asp.net mvc application.

```
<text> @azamsharp </text>
```

gives me the following error:

The name 'azamsharp' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@@azamsharp`

Razor see the `@` and thinks you're escaping into code, so it looks for a variable `azamsharp`. `@@` tells razor you want to print an `@` symbol, not escape into code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
@@azamsharp
```

That should work